# How effectively add not existing entities from input List to DB in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an entity `User` with primary key property `UCO`.

I would like to write a method `AddUsers` that adds all users from given list to the database. Problem is that when admin tries to add list in which is a user that already exists in the database, then an exception is thrown.

My solution that adds only Users that are not in database is here:

```
public void AddUsers(List<UserDTO> users)
{
    using (var db = new AppDbContext())
    {
        var existingUsers = Mapper.Map<List<UserDTO>>(db.Users.ToList());

        db.Users.AddRange(
                Mapper.Map<List<User>>(users
                    .Where(user => !existingUsers
                        .Select(u => u.UCO)
                        .Contains(user.UCO))));
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

I would like to ask whether there is some more effective solution. If I had 10'000 users, then this would be very slow...

Thank you for answers :)

Comment: Which list is potentially big - `existingUsers`, `users` or both?

Comment: existingUsers is potentially big

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `users` list is not expected to be so big, you can avoid loading the potentially big `existingUsers` list at least in a two ways.

First, execute a single db query per each item in the `users` list (so totally `users.Count` queries):

```
using (var db = new AppDbContext())
{
    db.Users.AddRange(Mapper.Map<List<User>>(users
        .Where(user => !db.Users.Any(u => u.UCO == user.UCO))));
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Second, execute a single db query for retrieving the subset of the `UCO` of the items from `users` list that exists in the database, then use it for excluding them from add:

```
using (var db = new AppDbContext())
{
    var userUCOs = users.Select(u => u.UCO);
    var existingUserUCOs = new HashSet<int>(db.Users
        .Where(u => userUCOs.Contains(u.UCO))
        .Select(u => u.UCO));
    db.Users.AddRange(Mapper.Map<List<User>>(users
        .Where(u => !existingUserUCOs.Contains(u.UCO))));
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

(if the `UCO` type is not `int`, just use `HashSet<UCO_Type>`)